# React Native как сделать компонент с зависимым от свойства состоянием?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

У меня есть компонент с кнопкой в которую передается свойство `quantity`.
От этого свойства зависит, какое состояние `isActive` будет у кнопки.
Сначала я это условие написал в конструкторе, всё работает чётко. Но на сценах имеющих свои состояния в момент перерисовки сцены кнопка также перерисовывается, но без участия конструктора. В итоге после смены свойства `quantity` состояние не меняется.

Если я уберу состояние `isActive` и буду использовать только свойство `quantity`, я не смогу влиять на отображение. Потому что такого метода как `setProp` не существует. А если я установлю значение напрямую в `this.props` и выполню `forceUpdate` может быть сработает, но мне кажется это костыльное решение. Подскажите, как наладить связь или как лучше сделать?

Screen.js

```
<Favorite quantity={data.favorite_count} id={data.id} />
```

Favorite.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class Favorite extends Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if (this.props.quantity > 0)
      this.state.isActive = true;
  }
  render() {
    let icon;

    if (this.state.isActive)
      icon = require('../assets/btn-unfavorite.png');
    else
      icon = require('../assets/btn-favorite.png');

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={this.props.style} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
        <Image source={icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  onPress() {
    this.setState(previousState => (
      { isActive: !previousState.isActive }
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит использовать componentDidUpdate. Есть getDerivedStateFromProps, раньше был componentWillReceiveProps.

Можно еще проще сделать...

```
<Favorite key={quantity} />
```

При изменении key react пересоздает компонент.

Comment: Хм, `getDerivedStateFromProps` вызывается даже при первоначальном монтировании, не придется дублировать код в конструкторе. Спасибо, опробую.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением метода `componentDidUpdate`, подробная информация в [документации](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidupdate) к обычному `react`. Если будут другие предложения с радостью ознакомлюсь.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class Favorite extends Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if (this.props.quantity > 0)
      this.state.isActive = true;
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.quantity !== prevProps.quantity) {
      this.setState({ isActive: (this.props.quantity > 0) });
    }
  }
  render() {
    let icon;

    if (this.state.isActive)
      icon = require('../assets/btn-unfavorite.png');
    else
      icon = require('../assets/btn-favorite.png');

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={this.props.style} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
        <Image source={icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  onPress() {
    this.setState(previousState => (
      { isActive: !previousState.isActive }
    ));
  }
}
```